# Missing props mapper in @apollo/react-hooks useQuery

Tags: react-apollo

In the older react-apollo and now also in [@apollo/react-hoc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc/), it was possible to map the API's response to another format by passing a function:

> The config.props property allows you to define a map function that takes the props [...] and allows you to compute a new props

This feature provided a way to remove ugly conversion code from the component by defining the Apollo HOC elsewhere, and since it only ran when data changed, no memoization was necessary.

I can't see how to do this with `useQuery`. Hooks can only be used directly inside React components ([Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)), so all I can think of is something like:

```js
import { fooQuery, mapFoo } from 'api';
...
const { data } = mapFoo(useQuery(fooQuery))
```

which might be acceptable, but it runs `mapFoo` on each render, and with `useMemo` it becomes too much:

```js
const bar = useQuery(barQuery); // unwanted value
const memoBar = useMemo(() => mapBar(bar), [bar])
```

I didn't find anyone else looking for this lost feature either, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the omittance of `props` is intentional and that a modern way to rewrite these transforming/memoizing HOCs without cluttering components would be to create a custom hook per query that encapsulates useQuery and useMemo.